# new line escape character does not return arguments properly - JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a function that takes in three parameters, creates a variable that assigns all three strings, to one printable string on three lines. I have tried the following:

```js
function generateHaiku(a, b, c) {
  var haiku = 'a\nb\nc';
  return haiku;
}
var example = generateHaiku("hi", "its", "me");
console.log(example);
```

but instead of returning the haiku, it returns
a
b
c

i want it to return

hi
its
me
(hi on first line, its on second line, me on third line)

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Normal strings do not perform terpolation.  Template Literals do.  `\`${a}\n${b}\``

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to make the haiku var a string literal:

```js
function generateHaiku(a,b,c) {
  var haiku = `${a}\n${b}\n${c}`;
  return haiku;
}
var example=generateHaiku("hi","its","me");
console.log(example);
```

Comment: Thank you , this worked well. I found out the answer that my teacher wanted without using this way that you posted. It goes as following :

line1 + "\n" + line2 + "\n" + line3